# Datatype for a Persisted Computed Column? Should I Convert/Cast When Creating It?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2016, datatypes, computed-column

What is the Datatype for a Persisted Computed Column?

(a) Does SQL Server automatically infer it?

(b) Also is better to cast it as a datatype, so SQL does not spend time to find what data type it is?

```
create table dbo.CustomerTransaction
(
   CustomerTransactionId int primary key identity(1,1),
   CustomerId int,
   Price decimal(10,2),
   Quantity int,
   TotalAmount as CustomerId * Price PERSISTED  -- should I cast as cast(CustomerId* Price as decimal(10,2) ??
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information turned into a Community Wiki answer from this question on Stack Overflow: [What is the data type of a computed column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554318/what-is-the-data-type-of-a-computed-column)

It's determined by the value with the [highest datatype precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

You can use `sql_variant_property` to determine what datatype a literal expression is [as per my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428538/curly-braces-in-t-sql/7428636#7428636). e.g. `2147483648` is interpreted as `numeric(10,0)` rather than `bigint`.

In addition, if you want to force a specific data type instead of relying on data type precedence, you can use `CONVERT` or `CAST` in the computation to force it (assuming all potential outcomes are compatible with the type you choose). This can be very useful in cases where, by default, you end up with a wider data type than you intended; the most common use case I've seen is when you end up with an INT instead of, say, a BIT:

```
Active1 AS CASE WHEN something THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
Active2 AS CONVERT(BIT, CASE WHEN something THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

In this case `Active1` is an `INT` (4 bytes) while `Active2` is a `BIT` (1 byte - or less, potentially, if it is adjacent to other `BIT` columns).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerTransaction

(  CustomerTransactionId int primary key identity(1,1),
   CustomerId int,
   Price decimal(10,2),
   Quantity int,
   TotalAmount as (cast(CustomerId AS decimal(10,2)) * cast(Price AS decimal(10,2))) PERSISTED
)
```